# Ruby on rails and photoswipe

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, photoswipe

Im having a bit of trouble making photoswipe work for my rails project.

I can show url images using href in the lightbox type gallery by photoswipe but when I try to show pictures uploaded by users and use the image_tag it will not work!

The code under the "Original gallery" heading is how I currently display images from the database and under the "Test gallery" is how photoswipe displays images using href. Im sure its something simple I'm missing but how can I combine the two to show the images from my ruby project in the photoswipe provided code?

[image]

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: No which is the most annoying part! you'd think it would be a simple add the top code into the part of the test in between the a tags.

Comment: Do you use any gems like paperclip to upload images?

Comment: I'm using carrierwave